# How can I do to show three params when I click on the select using react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a select such as :

```
<Select id='1' list={[...this.state.dictionnary]}/>
```

where `this.state.dictionnary` is like this :

```
state = {
        dictionnary: [
            {value: "a", name: "ab"},
        ]}
```

And the component select is like this :

```
class Select extends Component {

    handleChange()
    {
        // I would like to show 1, a and ab
        // 1 is the id of the select
        // a and ab are value and name of 
  };
    render() {
        return (
            <select onChange={this.handleChange} className="custom-select">{this.props.list.map(option => (
                <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>))}
            </select>
        )
    }
}

export default Select;
```

I would like to show some informations using the `handleChange()` function like the id, name and value.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean, to get selected value?

Comment: selected value and the id too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the option so the value has the entire object to get it later in the handleChange. Also, to access the same `this` with the props in the handleChange method you need to use an arrow function:

```
<select onChange={(e) => this.handleChange} className="custom-select">
    {this.props.list.map((option) => (
      <option key={option.value} value={option}>
        {option.name}
      </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

By default, the onChange handler gets the event param so you can get the target and  the props:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.props.id, value, name);
}
```

Comment: thank you but I don't achieve to get the id using `this.props.id` :/

Comment: Is `this` undefined inside handleChange? If so, use an arrow function like so `onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}`. If it works I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Alavaro answer, you need to `split` after getting the value to remote `,`

```
 handleChange = e => {
    const [value, name] = e.target.value.split(',')
    console.log({ id: this.props.id, value, name})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange} className="custom-select">
        {this.props.list.map((option, index) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={[option.value, option.name]} >
            { option.name }
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to get the index but the param id which is in the select. :/

Comment: Updated, check again